# Setting same instance of widget not working

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qgridlayout

I have a pyqt application and when using the same instance of the QLabel class on the gridlayout it is not working. I see only one instance being displayed.

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QToolTip, QPushButton, QMessageBox, QAction, qApp, QMenu, QTextEdit, QToolBar, QMdiArea, QGridLayout, QLabel, QDialog
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont, QIcon, QPainter, QVector2D
from PyQt5.Qt import QDesktopWidget, QMainWindow, Qt, QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout,\
    QLineEdit
from PyQt5.QtCore import QPoint


class Example(QDialog):
    count = 0
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Example, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)            
        self.initUI()


    def initUI(self):
        grid = QGridLayout()
        a1 = QLabel('alphanumeric characters')
        a2 = QLabel('alphanumeric characters')

        grid.addWidget(QLabel('Name'), 1, 0)
        grid.addWidget(QLineEdit(), 1, 1)
        grid.addWidget(QLabel('only alphanumeric'), 1, 2)
        grid.addWidget(QLabel('Street1'), 2, 0)
        grid.addWidget(QLineEdit(), 2, 1)
        grid.addWidget(QLabel('only alphanumeric'), 2, 2)
        grid.addWidget(QLabel('Street2'), 3, 0)
        grid.addWidget(QLineEdit(), 3, 1)
        grid.addWidget(QLabel('only alphanumeric'), 3, 2)
        grid.addWidget(QLabel('City'), 3, 0)
        grid.addWidget(QLineEdit(), 3, 1)
        grid.addWidget(QLabel('only alphanumeric'), 3, 2)

        self.setLayout(grid)
        self.setGeometry(500, 500, 500, 500)
        self.setWindowTitle('Lines')
        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
#     ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: typo: change `grid.addWidget(a1, 1, 0)
        grid.addWidget(a1, 1, 1)` to `grid.addWidget(a1, 1, 0)
        grid.addWidget(a2, 1, 1)`

Comment: Can't I use the same instance - a1?  My grid is going to have 3 columns and multiple rows..Most of the 3rd column will just contain informational msg - 'only alphanumeric characters"

Comment: You could explain yourself better, try changing both lines to: grid.addWidget(a1, 1, 0, 2, 1)

Comment: you can not use the same instance, what do you want to get?

Comment: I have edited the code, if you notice I have create multiple QLabel instance just to display 'only alphanumeric' text on column 3 of the grid.

Comment: okay, that's another thing, your initial example was very confusing that made me think he was a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First the coordinates start from (0, 0), so that part I have corrected.

Going to the problem, you do not have to add one to one, the `addWidget()` method is overloaded, so there is a 4 and 5 argument that indicates the span in the row and column, respectively.

> void  addWidget(QWidget *widget, int row, int column, Qt::Alignment
>   alignment = ...)
>
> void  addWidget(QWidget *widget, int fromRow, int fromColumn, int
>   **rowSpan**, int **columnSpan**, Qt::Alignment alignment = ...)

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QDialog, QGridLayout, QLabel, QLineEdit


class Example(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Example, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)            
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        grid = QGridLayout(self)
        a1 = QLabel('alphanumeric characters')
        a2 = QLabel('alphanumeric characters')

        grid.addWidget(QLabel('Name'), 0, 0)
        grid.addWidget(QLineEdit(), 0, 1)
        grid.addWidget(QLabel('Street1'), 1, 0)
        grid.addWidget(QLineEdit(), 1, 1)
        grid.addWidget(QLabel('Street2'), 2, 0)
        grid.addWidget(QLineEdit(), 2, 1)
        grid.addWidget(QLabel('City'), 3, 0)
        grid.addWidget(QLineEdit(), 3, 1)

        grid.addWidget(QLabel('only alphanumeric'), 0, 2, 4, 1)

        self.setGeometry(500, 500, 500, 500)
        self.setWindowTitle('Lines')
        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
#     ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```